How to locate CA bundle used by pip?
Pip documentation says:

By default, pip will perform SSL certificate verification for network
connections it makes over HTTPS. These serve to prevent
man-in-the-middle attacks against package downloads. This does not use
the system certificate store but, instead, uses a bundled CA
certificate store from certifi.

However, if a fresh Python installation certifi is missing:
% docker run -it --rm python:3.10 bash
root@067205989d2e:/# python -m certifi
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named certifi

Still, pip is using some store, and it is likely different from the path provided by certifi module. So what that path is?

@phd please follow the documentation link, pip does not use OS cert store.

OK, I found that pip bundles certifi under _vendor package directory. The directory of packages can by found through
python -m site
The full path can look like
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/certifi/cacert.pem
